# Swap columns of a file - Linux (exact position, not word)

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

I would like to know how to swap columns (the exact character) of a file with Linux (using cut, awk, sed or whatever you can help me with).
I have seen how to swap a whole expression (using delimiters) and whole words.

Example:

```
128934
38 2008
```

Swapping column 3 with 5:

```
123984
3802 08
```

Another way to ask this, would be swap the 3rd char of each row with the 5th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unwieldy, with sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(..)(.)(.)(.)/\1\4\3\2/' infile
123984
3802 08
```

This captures the first five characters of each line in four groups and then rearranges them. `-E` is just there for convenience; without it, we have to escape the parentheses as in `\(.\)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. The only problem would be in a big file, if i wanted to change the 30th char with the 88th (just an example). The group (..) in your answer would be something really big like (......29 dots...), is there a way to rewrite this, instead of doing a lot of dots?

Comment: `.{10}` is ten characters, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with gawk, mawk, nawk and busybox awk with this non-posix complient example:

```
awk -v FS='' -v OFS='' '{ t=$3; $3=$5; $5=t } 1' infile
```

Output:

```
123984
3802 08
```

Comment: You should mention that would only work with GNU awk (maybe some others?) since using a null char as the FS to split into characters is undefined behavior per POSIX. gawk will do what you want but some others definitely won't so YMMV but is by far the simplest approach if you have GNU tools.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good to know. I tested it succesfully with: gawk, mawk, nawk and busybox awk